# Add Soap Headers to XDocument

Tags: vb.net, soap, linq-to-xml, soapheader

I am creating an XDocument with the following structure:

```
 Dim xDocHandle As XDocument =
                                   New XDocument(
                                   New XDeclaration("1.0", Nothing, Nothing),
                                   New XElement("Element",
                                    New XElement("Dialogue",
                                    New XElement("Desc", AppDesc),
                                    New XElement("Num", Num),
                                    New XElement("Ref", Ref),
                                    New XElement("ms", Ms),
                                    New XElement("im", Im))
                                   ))
```

To have the following output:

```
<Element>
  <Dialogue>
    <Desc>test</Desc>
    <Num>1</Num>
    <Ref></Ref>
    <ms>2411616</ms>
    <im></im>
  </Dialogue>
</Element>
```

I want to add the following headers

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns="">
```

Should I add them as new `XDeclaration` , new `XElement`?
Whats the type of the soap headers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<soap:Envelope>` and `<soap:Body>` are clearly elements. You can do something like this to construct XML with soap header :

```
'create <Element> node :'
Dim element As XElement = New XElement("Element",
                                    New XElement("Dialogue",
                                    New XElement("Desc", AppDesc),
                                    New XElement("Num", Num),
                                    New XElement("Ref", Ref),
                                    New XElement("ms", Ms),
                                    New XElement("im", Im))
                                   )
'create <soap:Envelope> node and add <Element> as child of <soap:Body> :'
Dim soap As XNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
Dim soapEnvelope As XElement = New XElement(soap + "Envelope",
                                New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap", soap.NamespaceName),
                                New XAttribute(soap + "encodingStyle", "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"),
                                New XElement(soap + "Body", element))
'create XDocument and set <soap:Envelope> as content'
Dim xDocHandle As XDocument =
                           New XDocument(
                           New XDeclaration("1.0", Nothing, Nothing),
                            soapEnvelope
                           )
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
               soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
    <soap:Body>
        <Element>
          <Dialogue>
            <Desc>test</Desc>
            <Num>1</Num>
            <Ref></Ref>
            <ms>2411616</ms>
            <im></im>
          </Dialogue>
        </Element>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I want to add <soap:Body> an xmlns attribute, but when I'm doing that, <element> is automatically getting the xmlns attribute as well